"repeated measures ANOVA" vs "ANOVA with subject as random effect" vs "repeated measures ANOVA with subject as random effect"
What is the difference between running a repeated measures ANOVA (the measure is repeated across time for each subject) vs an ANOVA with a subject as a random effect?`
I have also seen mention of a "repeated measures ANOVA with subject as random effect".
For context I have 6 groups and 3 post-baseline time points per group/subject. Each subject is a member of one group. I would like to compare means of both different groups at the same time point (ex group 1 vs group 3 at time point B) and means of the same group at different time points (ex. group 1 at time point B vs group 1 at time point C).
I will use ls-means to compare means, but I don't really understand the differences between the above three model categories. If there even is a difference!
Thank you very much!

It might be helpful to have some example data to make it more clear. A simple example comes from table 4 of Winer, Brown, & Michels. The data has the following form:



person
drug
score




1
1
30


1
2
28


1
3
16


1
4
34


2
1
14


2
2
18


2
3
10


2
4
22



and so on for 5 persons.
In this data, drugs are repeatedly measured within the same person(s). So you could say that person is a random factor and drugs are a fixed, repeated factor.   I tend to work on mixed modeling problems, and I would analyze this data as follows:
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read_dta("https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/t43.dta")
dat <- dat %>% mutate(drug = as.factor(drug), person = as.factor(person))
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

# Random effects ANOVA ignoring drug
m0 <- lmer(score ~ 1  + (1|person), data = dat)
summary(m0, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")

fit.person_ran.aov <- aov(score ~ Error(person), data = dat)
summary(fit.person_ran.aov, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
Error: person
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  4  680.8   170.2               

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 15    811   54.07 

Now, let's add the repeated measure, drug. I use the Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom correction given that we are working with a tiny sample:
# Random effect with repeated measures (drug)
m1 <- lmer(score ~ 1 + drug + (1|person), data = dat)
summary(m1,ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
anova(m1, ddf=c("Kenward-Roger"))
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
drug  698.2  232.73     3    12  24.759 1.993e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Just to be sure, let's use aov() to see if things line up:
fit.person_drug.aov <- aov(score ~ drug + Error(person), data = dat)
summary(fit.person_drug.aov, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
Error: person
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  4  680.8   170.2               

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
drug       3  698.2   232.7   24.76 1.99e-05 ***
Residuals 12  112.8     9.4                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Hello @Erik, thank you very much and sorry for my very delayed response!  From what I understand in your example, the "repeated measures" is not explicitly given in any formula statement - it is just implicit form the structure. Is that right? How would one formulate a repeated measures ANOVA WITHOUT subject as a random effect. Is that the AOV example you give at the end? Thank you again!

One problem with not including subject as a random (or fixed) effect is that all the variance that is due to person gets inappropriately shoved into the residual. Second, the calculation of the F value (and test) is affected because the the influence of subject on drug response is not accounted for. There are mixed models for repeated measures that do not account for subject random effects but instead account for the repeated measures via an imposed residual correlation structure. Usually, you want at least 3 or 4 measurement occasions. See https://github.com/openpharma/mmrm

I didn't address your question about whether the aov() command infers structure from the model syntax, I believe it does. When you add Error(subject) it "knows" to differentiate between variables that vary within and between subjects. It then adjusts the denominator degrees of freedom in the F-tests appropriately.

Hello @erik ruzek, thank you very much for the explanation! Very helpful!

No problem @Rorio! If you found the answer helpful, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.
